# Kendo Grid select over multiple pages

Tags: kendo-grid

I have created a kendo grid using Asp.Net MVC wrappers. I have included a checkbox for selecting multiple rows made the wiring and everything works ok. However, I have issues, when I change page, or do a filtering as the selecting rows/checkbox disappear.

What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.PersistSelection(true)` to ensure rows remain selected when changing pages:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("rowSelection")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .PersistSelection(true)                
    .Navigatable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()                
        .Model(m=>m.Id("OrderID"))
        .PageSize(6)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
     )
```

Also ensure you have an id column declared in the DataSource, like `.Model(m=>m.Id("OrderID"))` in the example, otherwise it will fail.

Full details [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selection).

I had issues with the jQuery `grid.select()` however:

```
    var grid = $('#rowSelection').data('kendoGrid');
    var rows = grid.select();
```

This only seemed to return rows selected on the currently displayed page rather than all the rows selected across all the pages.

Comment: yes it should work... in 17 +  version not for 15 or older version

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for the grid.select() only returning the selected items on the displayed page?

Comment: @NiallMitch14 from recollection I created a JavaScript array, and on every user grid change added or removed from that array depending on the user action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedKeyNames() to get all items across all pages. E.g

```
   var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
   var selectedItems = grid.selectedKeyNames(); //they are comma delimited
```